# cant print the json content in table form in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

guys i know its dummy question but i have spent alot of hours in this and still cant reach .. i want print the json content in table form .. here is my code

```
[{
"id": 1,
"name": "name1",
"age": 67,
"feedback": "feedback1"
}, {
"id": 2,
"name": "name2",
"age": 30,
"feedback": "feedback2"
}, {
"id": 3,
"name": "name3",
"age": 59,
"feedback": "feedback3"
   }, {
"id": 4,
"name": "name4",
"age": 17,
"feedback": "feedback4"
}]
```

in javascript

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({

```
    url : 'data.json',
    error : function(that, e) {

        console.log(e);
    },
    success : function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(index1, MyList) {
            $.each(MyList, function(index2, item) {
                $('body').append('<div id="div'+ index2+'" />');
                $('#div' + index2).append(MyList[index2]);
            });
        });

    }
});

});
```

here is my output

```
 1234
 name1name2name3name4
 67305917
 feedback1feedback2feedback3feedback4
```

and i want to make it in table form like this

```
1 name1 67 feedback1
2 name2 39 feedback2
3 name3 59 feedback3
4 name4 17 feedback4
```

Comment: what is your datatype when you execute the AJAX call ?

Comment: Please show your entire ajax call code.

Comment: i am writing it in JS file

Comment: this is my entire code and i am putting it in external JS and including it in JSP

Comment: if you are going to use the json data format then while ajax call you should pass dataType: "json" , have you added that  ?

Comment: like this . 
 $.ajax(
   {

      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      url: url,
      data: { get_member: id },
      success: function( response ) 
      { }  });

Comment: yes i did ... but the output still the same

Answer (score 0):

try this snippet.you dont need two loops. just loop on items and build the bale row markup with data in each item.

```js
data = [{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "name1",
  "age": 67,
  "feedback": "feedback1"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "name2",
  "age": 30,
  "feedback": "feedback2"
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "name": "name3",
  "age": 59,
  "feedback": "feedback3"
}, {
  "id": 4,
  "name": "name4",
  "age": 17,
  "feedback": "feedback4"
}]
var table_markyp = "<table>";
$.each(data, function(i, v) {
  table_markyp += '<tr><td>' + v.id + '</td><td>' + v.name + '</td><td>' + v.age + '</td><td>' + v.feedback + '</td><tr>';

})
table_markyp += '</table>';
$('body').append(table_markyp)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

create a container with an id e.g `<div id="tablecontainer">` and this below will generate a table with the results

if you want headers you can take one object from data e.g `data[0]`, perform `Object.keys(data[0])` and attached them to a `<tr/> <th/>` object like the row method below

```
success: function(data) {
  var container = $('#tablecontainer');
  var table = $('<table></table>');
  data.forEach(function(datarow) {
    var row = $("<tr />");
    for (var item in datarow) {
      row.append($("<td>" + datarow[item] + "</td>"));
    }
    table.append(row);
  });
  container.append(table);
}
```

example output with headers:

```js
var data = [{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "name1",
  "age": 67,
  "feedback": "feedback1"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "name2",
  "age": 30,
  "feedback": "feedback2"
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "name": "name3",
  "age": 59,
  "feedback": "feedback3"
}, {
  "id": 4,
  "name": "name4",
  "age": 17,
  "feedback": "feedback4"
}];


var container = $('body');
var table = $('<table></table>');

var head = $("<tr />");
var keys = Object.keys(data[0]);
keys.forEach(function(key){
 head.append($("<th>" + key + "</th>"))
})
table.append(head);


data.forEach(function(datarow) {
  var row = $("<tr />");
  for (var item in datarow) {
    row.append($("<td>" + datarow[item] + "</td>"));
  }
  table.append(row);
});
container.append(table);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is , you have to create and HTML structure, 
so that all the result will be displayed with a line by line and for that you can follow the table structure,.

check this code.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>        
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "data.json",
                error : function(that, e) {                    
                    console.log(e);
                },
                success : function(data) {
                    var Mytable = "<table>";
                    $.each(data, function(temp, res) {
                      Mytable += 
                              '<tr>\n\
                                    <td>' + res.id + '</td>\n\
                                    <td>' + res.name + '</td>\n\
                                    <td>' + res.age + '</td>\n\
                                    <td>' + res.feedback + '</td>\n\
                                <tr>';
                    });
                    Mytable += '</table>';
                    $('body').append(Mytable);                    
                }
            }); 
        });
    </script>
</html>
```